# ¿Como Activar los permisos de Lectura en Java?

Tags: java, android, archivo

Hola estoy desarrollando codigo para obtener la información de un archivo, el archivo puede estar en la memoria interna o externa de un smartphone con sistema operativo Android, utilizo la clase File para generar la ruta path del archivo, y este parametro se lo paso a la clase:

```
bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
```

para obtener la información del archivo en un arreglo de bytes, la cuestión es que el archivo existe en la ruta que le pasó, pero el sistema de android me devuelve un error como el siguiente:

No se puede leer
Permiso Lectura: false
Permiso Escritura: false
Path: /storage/emulated/0/Ejemplos Archivos MSR/A3R 00000000000000000000 20201217230108.msr

Si le quito los la parte de verificación de permisos devuelve el siguiente error:

I/System.out: File /storage/emulated/0/Ejemplos Archivos MSR/A3R 00000000000000000000 20201217230108.msr
Message /storage/emulated/0/Ejemplos Archivos MSR/A3R 00000000000000000000 20201217230108.msr
Reason null
W/System.err: **java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /storage/emulated/0/Ejemplos Archivos MSR/A3R 00000000000000000000 20201217230108.msr**

Dejo mi codigo, si alguien puede ayudarme sería bueno.

```
File file = new File(Path_MSR);
byte[] bytes = null;
    if (file.exists() == true){
        if (file.canRead() == true){
            try {
                bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
            }catch (AccessDeniedException e){
                System.out.println("File "+e.getFile());
                System.out.println("Message "+e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Reason "+e.getReason());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("No se puede leer");
            System.out.println("Permiso Lectura: "+file.canRead());
            System.out.println("Permiso Escritura: "+file.canWrite());
            System.out.println("Path: "+file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("No existe");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define el permiso en tu AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

y debes requerir el permiso manualmente, puedes usar este mètodo:

```
private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
    }
}
```

Pero en este caso el error **AccessDeniedException** puede tambier ser causado porque el directorio al cual estas tratando de acceder no existe o la ruta es incorrecta.